# Compilation Error: Use of a deleted function

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

During compilation, the error is: `Node::Node() is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed`. This occurs on the line `Node *trans = new Node;` in `CreditCard.cpp`.

**CreditCard.h**

```
#ifndef CREDITCARD_H
#define CREDITCARD_H
#include <iostream>
#include "Money.h"

using namespace std;
using String = std::string;

struct Node{
    String name;
    Money cost;
    Node* next; 
};

class CreditCard{
    private:
        String ownerName;
        String cardNumber;
        Node* transaction;
    public:
        CreditCard(String, String);

        void Charge(String, Money);

        void Charge(String, int, int);

        void print();

};

#endif
```

The **CreditCard.cpp** is:

```
#include "CreditCard.h"

CreditCard::CreditCard(String name, String cardNo)
      :ownerName(name), cardNumber(cardNo){}

void CreditCard::Charge(String name, Money cost){
       Node *trans = new Node;        // *** This is the line with the error ***
       trans->name = name;
       trans->cost = cost;
       trans->next = transaction;
       transaction = trans;
  }

void CreditCard::Charge(String name, int euros, int centiments){
     Money m(euros, centiments);
     Charge(name, m);
  }

void CreditCard::print(){
     Node *p = transaction;
     // p = first;
     while(p){
         (p->cost.print());
         p=p->next;
     }
  }
```

`Money` is declared in `Money.cpp` and `Money.h`
**Money.cpp**

```
#include "Money.h"

Money::Money(int euros=0, int centimes=0)
    :euros(euros), centimes(centimes)
        {}
void Money::setMoney(int euros=0, int centimes=0){
    this->euros = euros;
    this->centimes = centimes;
}
void Money::print(){
    printf("%d,%d Euros\n", this->euros, this->centimes);
}
// Operator Overloading (Operator+)
Money Money::operator+(Money other){
    Money total;
    total.centimes = this->centimes + other.centimes;
    if (total.centimes >= 100){
        total.euros = total.euros + (total.centimes / 100);
        total.centimes %= 100;  
    }
    total.euros += this->euros + other.euros;
    return total;
}
```

**Money.h**

```
#ifndef MONEY_H
   #define MONEY_H
    #include <iostream>

    class Money{
        private:
            int euros;
            int centimes;
        public:
            Money(int, int);
            void setMoney(int, int);
            void print();
            // Operator Overloading (Operator+)
            Money operator+(Money other);
    };

#endif
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also posting images of code is considered as bad. Please post sufficient code to reproduce as text.

Comment: `Money` cannot be default-constructed, and so neither can `Node`. But `CreditCard::Charge` in fact attempts to default-construct `Node`.

Comment: I updated the full code, now if you can tell what's the solution to the problem. @MikeCAT

Comment: @IgorTandetnik so what is the solution or what needs to be changed in the code?

Comment: Where is the full code? At least class declaration of `CreditCard` is missing. Declaration of `Money` is also missing.

Comment: @MikeCAT is it clear now ??

Comment: It's considered bad form to continuously change your question in a way that invalidates the answers. SO is meant to be a Q&A site, not a conversational bulletin board for continuous incremental code improvements. The right thing would be to ask *another* question with the different problem.

Comment: I will surely take care of that next time. But if you could please help me out now with this problem that would be great! @paxdiablo

Comment: Sorry, have little confidence that the question won't change again and I try to optimise my effort here on SO. Will have a look in an hour or so and, assuming no massive changes and no other good answers, will try again.

Comment: @Chiranjeev you need to declare the default parameters of your `Money` constructor in the header instead of in the cpp file. If you want it to be able act like a default constructor

Comment: @PeterT thanks! It worked, but can you tell the logic why this happened?

Answer (score 0):

You should define an explicit default constructor for `Node`:

```
struct Node{
    String name;
    Money cost;
    Node* next; 

    Node() : name(""), cost(0,0), next(NULL) {}  // this should do the trick
};
```